# How to update authorized networks for a GKE Cluster from command-line with display names?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When using the google cloud console, I can navigate to my GKE cluster in the browser and see/edit the "control plane authorized networks" like this:

[image]

I've blurred the image, but essentially what you see is a list of "display name" - "cidr block" pairs. From the command line, I you can update the authorized networks using:

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --region=REGION \
     --enable-master-authorized-networks \
     --master-authorized-networks=59.28.227.255/32,59.28.227.254/32
```

But I also want to specify a display name for each CIDR block. How can I specify a display name when updating the authorized networks for a GKE cluster from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible to specify a display name when adding a new master authorized network or when modifying an existing one using the gcloud command. A workaround would be to do it through the console.

To [add an authorized network to an existing cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks#add):

1. Go to the Google Kubernetes Engine page in the Google Cloud console.
2. Click the name of the cluster you want to modify.
3. Under Networking, in the Control plane authorized networks field, click `Edit control plane authorized networks`.
4. Select the `Enable control plane authorized networks checkbox`.
5. Click Add authorized network.
6. Enter a `Name` for the network.
7. For Network, enter a CIDR range that you want to grant access to your cluster control plane.
8. Click Done. Add additional authorized networks as needed.
9. Click Save Changes.

To add a display name to an existing authorized network in an existing cluster

1. Click the name of the cluster you want to modify.
2. Under Networking, in the Control plane authorized networks field, click `Edit control plane authorized networks`.
3. Select the Enable control plane authorized networks checkbox.
4. Click the `drop down arrow` next to the existing authorized network that you want to name
5. Add the name of the authorized network
6. Click Done and Save Changes

Meanwhile, a feature request has been submitted to address the limitation. To stay updated on the status and progress of this feature request, please follow this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123983759) to access the feature request page. Once there, click on the `+1` and `star` buttons to receive notifications regarding any updates.